# How to get url on form submit

Tags: php, forms, get, submit, edit

i just created a form and i am facing a problem on submit.

**Example:**

Here i have the link to edit.php where i get all the information with this link.

index.php

```
<a href="change/info/edit.php?url= '
. $row['url'] 
.'&title='. $row['title'] 
.'&info='. $row['info']   
.'&name='. $row['name']  
.'&date='. $row['date'] .' " target="_blank">Edit</a>
```

Here i get all the information from index.php like this here below:

edit.php :

```
<?php echo $_GET["title"]; ?>
<?php echo $_GET["info"]; ?>
<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?>
<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>
<?php echo $_GET["url"]; ?>
```

**EDIT:** Ares Draguna

```
<?php session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    // code for check server side validation
    if(empty($_SESSION['captcha_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['captcha_code'], $_POST['captcha_code']) != 0){ 


        $msg='<span class="fail">Please try again.</span>';// Captcha verification is incorrect.        

    }else{// Captcha verification is Correct. Final Code Execute here!

}
}
```

But when i hit the submit button and captcha is false the page refresh and i lose all the information, i have to hit back in the browser to see again all the information.

So what do i need to keep the information, when hit the submit button and captcha is false.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Im guessing that the html you have put in the index.php is in a echo statement?

Comment: Yes, is that the problem you think ?

Comment: so it reads like `echo '<a href="change/info/edit.php?url= '
. $row['url'] 
.'&title='. $row['title'] 
.'&info='. $row['info']   
.'&name='. $row['name']  
.'&date='. $row['date'] .' " target="_blank">Edit</a>';` ? Also what is the code after the edit? Is that the edit.php page or is it another page it isn't passing it through to? Also if you are in a modern browser you can right click and view the element and make sure the URL is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the information on the form, you can set some session variables like:

`$_SESSION['title'] = $_GET["title"];`

`$_SESSION['info'] = $_GET["info"];`
and so on... and the test it:

```
if(capcha == false) {
   //do something
} else {
   //unset the session variables
}
```

In this scenario, if the capcha is false, then you can repopulate the form inputs with what you have in session, so even after the page is reloaded you still have those information stored. If the capcha is true, then remember to unset the session vars.

However, if the exact same page refreshes, it means that you have the values in $_GET so you could use that with no problems. It really depends on how your code is structured.

**L.E:**

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $_SESSION['captcha_code'] = $_GET['captcha_code'];
    $_SESSION['other_info'] = $_GET['other_info'];
    // code for check server side validation
    if(empty($_SESSION['captcha_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['captcha_code'], $_POST['captcha_code']) != 0){ 
        $msg='<span class="fail">Please try again.</span>';// Captcha verification is incorrect.        
    }else{
       // Captcha verification is Correct. Final Code Execute here!
    }
}
```

And in the view file, check the session variables, so the session vars are set if isset submit post.

Hope it helps! 
Keep on coding! 
Ares.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just edited the file i try what you just posted but nothing happen. @Ares Draguna

Comment: What did happened? Dump the session var and see if you really have the values there. check the get var as well to compare

Comment: I added $_SESSION['title'] = $_GET["title"]; under if(empty($_SESSION['captcha_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['captcha_code'], $_POST['captcha_code']) != 0){ but nothing happen

Comment: check L.E... I explained some stuff there